# Nest.js: getting an Injectable() singleton reference inside of a regular class instance

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, inject

I have a standard config service in my nest.js application:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
 constructor(...) {...}

 someFunction(...) {...}
```

and it is available in my module through dependency injection.

I also have a regular class which I make instances of using 'new' where needed:

```
export class ConcreteClass {

  getUrl(): string {
    return this.configService.someFunction();
  }
}
```

---

How can I use the config service singleton instance provided in the module, in this concrete class, without passing a reference in the constructor like `new ConcreteClass(configServiceRef);`?

Comment: You should not create class with `new` while using Nest DI as only what you get from it is a mess.
Why do you do that this way?

Comment: My ConcreteClass is not something I need all the time like a singleton, and I dont need it in the scope of the module. It is just there to feed another service, specifically: I have an || @Injectable AxiosService implements ApiCommunicationService ||. it has one function: || exec<T, K>(networkRequest: NetworkRequest<T>): Promise<K>; ||.  and so || ConcreteClass extends NetworkRequest || and I use 'new' to create that specific network request and feed it to the axios service for execution... so, any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create an repro repo or it is sort of top-secret project

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is a 'stealth' work project